# Turn off Smart Folders display ".savedSearch" extension in Finder sidebar

Tags: finder, uti, smart-folders, sidebar

I held off upgrading my Mac Pro from Snow Leopard to Lion until I had replaced all the important apps that would no longer run.

So far it's OK, but one thing has me baffled is that my Smart Searches in the Finder sidebar all display a ".savedSearch" extension.

I've gone to Finder prefs and unchecked "Show all filename extensions" and I've done a Get Info… on the search themselves and made sure "Hide extension" is clicked.

Neither made a difference.

This doesn't happen on my MacBook, just the Mac Pro.

Any idea how to stop it?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to recreate your searches since the option to hide the extension is not present if "Show all extensions" is enabled.

Disable "Show all extensions" in Finder preferences (which you have done)
Create a new Search in Finder
Check the box "Hide Extension" in the resulting dialog

[image]

See the original author's explanation [here](http://christianboyce.blogspot.de/2011/08/bring-back-for-in-lion-finder-sidebar.html) for more information

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable "Show all Extensions" in Finder preferences like you have already done.  However, current saved searches will still show the extension.  Instead of recreating all of your saved searches all over again, just rename them and the saved search will be updated with a hidden extension.  Then you can go back and rename it again to its previous name.

Comment: You could also just reopen Finder with `osascript -e 'quit app "Finder"' && open -a Finder` or by logging out and back in.